# Filling column with data from another column in the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am new to SQL and this is probably fairly easy but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I am trying to fill a column with data pulled from another column in the same table.. in this case its a basketball database with box scores and I am trying to fill the column of opponent points (opp_pts) to match what their opponent for that game scored.  each game is matched by season_id and game_id.

the whole table is about 700 rows with a few hundred games and about 40 teams but a sample is below... this is an example of one game where the score was 84-81 but I want to fill opp_team_stats with the appropriate score

```
season_id   game_id   team_id     team_pts      opp_team_pts    
  U2018       140    U2018_19      84.0                         
  U2018       140    U2018_23      81.0
```

I have tried but have only been able to fill the whole column of opp_team_pts with with 84 which is obviously incorrect

```
UPDATE box_scores 
SET opp_team_pts = (SELECT box_scores.team_pts
FROM box_scores
WHERE box_scores.season_id=box_scores.season_id AND box_scores.game_id=box_scores.game_id);
```

I'm sure the code is probably redundant but that is as far as I got, I understand why it filled the way it did but can't seem to figure out how to fix it... I may be on the wrong track but hopefully can get a bit of help

Comment: How do you know what the opposition team is?

Comment: in this case i singled out one game of many in the table in the snippet i posted so these two teams played each other which is denoted by the game_id 140 so the score was 84-81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each game has exactly two teams, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE box_scores
    SET opp_team_pts = (SELECT bs2.team_pts
                        FROM box_scores bs2
                        WHERE bs2.season_id = box_scores.season_id AND
                              bs2.game_id = box_scores.game_id AND
                              bs2.team_id <> box_scores.team_id
                       );
```

SQLite does not support `FROM` in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @GDolan . . . The question is how many teams are in a game.  If there are more than two, then this will return an error (subquery returns more than one row).

Comment: i tried running it and it returned in an error in the first line near "bs": syntax error

Comment: @GDolan . . . That is irritating.  The syntax diagram for SQLite shows that it accepts a qualified table name there (https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/qualified-table-name.html), but it doesn't seem to work.  I fixed the answer.